# Serializing not-nested objects as nested

Tags: c#, serialization

I have two objects - Book and Shelf.

```
class Book
{

}

class Shelf
{

}
```

As you can see, they are not inner.

How to serialize them, so that I get xml that looks like this:

```
<Book bookAttribute="">
    <Shelf>bla</Shelf>
    <Shelf>bla1</Shelf>
</Book>
```

Comment: Considering there is no relationship in your class example, nor the information bla, bla1, and nothing about bookAttribute in your example, it's difficult for me to read your mind and come up with a solution.

Comment: Not to mention that the XML shows 1 book and 2 shelves ... Going to need more info here!

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for serialization? It looks like you are just trying to author an XML document. In which case, yes it is possible. If you are truly after serialization then your object model will need to reflect the XML you expect to be written.

Comment: Would be happy to help answer it, but I'm not sure it is remotely answerable in the current form

Comment: I can only say `Console.WriteLine(@"<Book bookAttribute=""""> <Shelf>bla</Shelf>  <Shelf>bla1</Shelf> </Book>");` :)

Comment: Marc is right, how can one book be on two shelves?  Did someone cut it in half?  Maybe thats what the bookAttribute=".5" is for.

Comment: @ The last comment, I can perceive that a bookstore might place a book in "Sci-Fi", in "Fiction" and in "Front Window". Same book. Three locations. It all depends on what the data is doing and whether the count needs to be specific to each location or just a count as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a crack at it here and assume that with the info you've given you need a class structure like this:

```
class Book
{
    [XmlAttribute("bookAttribute")]
    public string bookAttribute = "";

    [XmlElement("Shelf")]
    List<Shelf> Shelves = new List<Shelf>();
}

class Shelf
{

}
```

Then when you create the programmatic relationship between a book and shelves (which seems backward to me - but I don't know what the whole scenario is) you can then loop it during your "Save" routine to write it as XML.

In the event that the original structures cannot be modified, you can still derive classes from them:

```
class ExpandedBook: Book
{
    [XmlAttribute("bookAttribute")]
    public string bookAttribute = "";

    [XmlElement("Shelf")]
    List<Shelf> Shelves = new List<Shelf>();
}
```

...unless the class is sealed in which case you'll have to create ugly arrays of arrays.